# How to correctly use "merge" method in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to solve Exercise 5, Chapter 6 of book "Java SE 8 for Really Impatient" by "Cay S Horstman". Here is the question:

Write an application in which multiple threads read all words from a collection of files. Use a ConcurrentHashMap> to track files in which each word occurs. Use merge method to update the map.

I tried to solve this exercise like this:
I created 4 files file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt

file1.txt has these contents:

```
Word1
```

file2.txt has these contents:

```
Word1 Word2
```

file3.txt has these contents:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3
```

file4.txt has these contents:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4
```

I implemented a class "Problem5.java" that gets the list of above 4 files in specified directory. This class has a static ConcurrentHashMap "stringToFileMap" that will be updated using "merge" method. This class creates a StringToFileMapper object for each file and then invokes all the callables using executor service. Once the futures are returned from executor service, it prints out the contents of the concurrent hash map.

**Problem5.java**

```
package problem5;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Problem5 {
public static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<File>>  stringToFileMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private File[] files;
private ExecutorService  executorService;
public Problem5(String dirName){
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    File dir =  new File(dirName);
    files = dir.listFiles((dir1, name) -> name.endsWith(".txt"));
}

public void execute() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    List<Future<Long>> futureList;
    Collection<StringToFileMapper> callables = new ArrayList<>();
    for(File file: files){
        callables.add(new StringToFileMapper(file));
    }
    futureList = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
    stringToFileMap.forEach((String key, Set<File> files) -> {
        StringBuilder fileNames = new StringBuilder();
        for(File file: files){
            fileNames.append(file.getName());
            fileNames.append(", ");

        }
        System.out.println(key+" is present in files "+fileNames.toString());
    });
    System.out.println("Hashmap size = "+ stringToFileMap.size());
    executorService.shutdown();
    stringToFileMap.clear();
}
}
```

I implemented a callable class "StringToFileMapper.java" that reads words from a file and updates concurrentHashmap "stringToFileMap".

**StringToFileMapper.java :**

```
package problem5;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public final class StringToFileMapper implements Callable<Long> {

private final File file;
public StringToFileMapper(File file){
    this.file = file;
}


@Override
public Long call() throws Exception {
    Long count = 0l;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.file))){
        Set<File> fileSet = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        fileSet.add(this.file);
        Stream<String> lineStream = reader.lines();
        lineStream.forEach(line -> {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for(String word: words){
                //count = count.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                BiFunction<Set<File>, Set<File>, Set<File>> reMappingFunction = (Set<File> oldSet, Set<File> newSet) -> {
                    oldSet.addAll(newSet);
                    return oldSet;
                };
                System.out.println("Word " +word+" is in "+ this.file.getName());

                Problem5.stringToFileMap.merge(word, fileSet, reMappingFunction);
            }

        });
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

As you can see above, I used BiFunction "reMappingFunction" along with "merge" function in ConcurrentHashMap.

Problem5.java will be called from main function that instantiates it with directory path of text files and calls its "execute" method.

```
import problem1.Problem1;
import problem3.Problem3;
import problem5.Problem5;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Problem5 problem5 = new Problem5("src/problem1");
    problem5.execute();
}
}
```

When i execute above above program, it sometimes prints the correct output and at other times it prints wrong output.

**Correct Output**

```
objc[36588]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1064e64c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1065ae4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Word Word1 is in file1.txt
Word Word1 is in file2.txt
Word Word2 is in file2.txt
Word Word1 is in file3.txt
Word Word2 is in file3.txt
Word Word3 is in file3.txt
Word Word1 is in file4.txt
Word Word2 is in file4.txt
Word Word3 is in file4.txt
Word Word4 is in file4.txt
Word4 is present in files file4.txt, 
Word2 is present in files file4.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, 
Word3 is present in files file4.txt, file3.txt, 
Word1 is present in files file4.txt, file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, 
Hashmap size = 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Wrong Output**

```
objc[36672]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10c8f04c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10c9b84e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Word Word1 is in file2.txt
Word Word1 is in file1.txt
Word Word2 is in file2.txt
Word Word1 is in file3.txt
Word Word2 is in file3.txt
Word Word3 is in file3.txt
Word Word1 is in file4.txt
Word Word2 is in file4.txt
Word Word3 is in file4.txt
Word Word4 is in file4.txt
Word4 is present in files file4.txt, 
Word2 is present in files file4.txt, file2.txt, file1.txt, file3.txt, 
Word3 is present in files file4.txt, file3.txt, 
Word1 is present in files file4.txt, file2.txt, file1.txt, file3.txt, 
Hashmap size = 4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see in above wrong output, Output from concurrent hashmap in Problem 5.java is wrong, where as output from sysout in StringToFileMapper.java is correct.

I am not able to figure out why above program is not working sometimes.

Comment: " Write an application in which multiple threads" I do not see where you are using multiple threads at all. You are not implementing runnable nor extending thread class

Comment: My bad. I just realized this was a Java 8 New feature, my school is only teaching us Java 7

Comment: @JeremiahStillings I am creating multiple threads using executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); and  invoking multiple threads using  executorService.invokeAll(callables);

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this problem. BiFunction argument to merge method has to return a new set instead of modifying existing set. Correct "BiFunction" argument is :

```
BiFunction<Set<File>, Set<File>, Set<File>> reMappingFunction = (Set<File> oldSet, Set<File> newSet) -> {
                    Set<File> temp = new HashSet<>();
                    temp.addAll(newSet);
                    temp.addAll(oldSet);
                    return temp;
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it **simpler** in real **multi-thread** way.

```
@Test
public void testConcurrentHashMap() {
    File folder = new File("/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1");
    Map<String, Set<File>> wordFileMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(folder.listFiles()).parallel().forEach(file -> {
        out.println(file.getPath());
        out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        List<String> words = readWordsFromFilePath(file.getPath());
        words.stream().forEach(word -> wordFileMap.merge(word, new HashSet<>(), (oldSet, newSet) -> {
            newSet.addAll(oldSet);
            return newSet;
        }).add(file));
    });
    wordFileMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        out.println("\"" + entry.getKey() + "\" in " + entry.getValue().size() + " file(s)");
    });
}
```

The some output demo:

```
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_2.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_3.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_6.java
main
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_11.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_1.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_8.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_7.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_4.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
/Users/lhearen/programs/JavaSe8Solutions/src/test/chap1/Sol_9.java
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
"temporary" in 1 file(s)
"ArrayList" in 2 file(s)
"rootDir" in 2 file(s)
```